# CSS3 easeOutBack issue when applying translate3d

Tags: css

If I set the translate3d property by default on my selector and then change translate3d by adding another class, it causes the bounceOutBack cubic easing to not work.  It seems to just default to easeIn

```
.content {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
    /*adding the below will mess up my bounceOutBack set above*/
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

If you add this class, below, to the .content selector with translate3d set above the easeOutback does not work.  I am not seeing this issue with any other custom easing types.  Sorry for not creating a fiddle to see this happening.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  Only testing in Chrome for now.  Thanks for any help.

```
.content.animate {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Comment: Your implicit translate is 0,0,0. There is no purpose in my opinion to specify it. And for a simple :hover action for me it works. Take a second look and add a simple hover effect to simplify things as you construct your transition.

Comment: I understand that setting 0,0,0 doesn't need to be set. But, in reality for what I am doing I start with a translateX of -200px. I just set 0,0,0 to maybe understand why this is happening.  I could put any number in there, as long as you specific it from the initial selector, the easing does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, may be it was some kind of Chrome bug.

Now it works ok

```
.content {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
    /*adding the below will mess up my bounceOutBack set above*/
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

body:hover .content {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNY9L/1/)